# sed pattern matching with deletion over a line

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I want to delete only some spaces(say 4) after the `line$#*425 with space`

I am not able to complete it please suggest

```
echo "line$#*425 with space          " | sed 's/ /\1 \2/g'
```

i am thinking of using `od -b` also but still not able to figure it out

how do i do it

**NOTE**:spaces could be a normal " " or a tab character also

**EDIT**:heres how i did a test to check for the below answer

```
[root@testgfs2 test]$echo -e "line$#*425 with space \t     "  | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{4\}$//' | od -b
0000000 154 151 156 145 060 052 064 062 065 040 167 151 164 150 040 163
0000020 160 141 143 145 040 011 040 012
0000030
```

the deletion is happening not after the space word but at the end of line.
the tab character(**011**) is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't seem to match your question. Your code sample has no groupings, so `\1` and `\2` don't reference anything. Here's what it sounds like you're asking for:

```
sed 's/space[[:blank:]]\{4\}/space/' <<< "line$#*425 with space          "
```

Comment: i guess,but this will delete charters at the end of the line i want the deletion to happen after the word `space`

Comment: @munish - See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the part(s) you want to keep in a group. Don't forget to quote the characters that need quoting in the regex (`\[.*^$`).

```
sed -e 's/\(line\$#\*425 with space\)[ \t][ \t][ \t][ \t]/\1/'
```

If your sed doesn't support `\t` to mean a tab character, replace `\t` by a literal tab character.